# Why do i get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] for source_directory in Azure ML Cartpole tutorial?

Tags: docker, azure-machine-learning-service, openai-gym, azureml-python-sdk

I have followed the steps described in [Cartpool notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/f45b8152218cbf5e40f44b983b459fe1c71c730e/how-to-use-azureml/reinforcement-learning/cartpole-on-single-compute/cartpole_sc.ipynb), but when I come to training the cartpole agent running the following cell:

```
from azureml.core import RunConfiguration, ScriptRunConfig, Experiment
from azureml.core.runconfig import DockerConfiguration, RunConfiguration

training_algorithm = "PPO"
rl_environment = "CartPole-v0"
video_capture = True
if video_capture:
    algorithm_config = '\'{"num_gpus": 0, "num_workers": 1, "monitor": true}\''
else:
    algorithm_config = '\'{"num_gpus": 0, "num_workers": 1, "monitor": false}\''

script_name = 'cartpole_training.py'
script_arguments = [
    '--run', training_algorithm,
    '--env', rl_environment,
    '--stop', '\'{"episode_reward_mean": 200, "time_total_s": 300}\'',
    '--config', algorithm_config,
    '--checkpoint-freq', '2',
    '--checkpoint-at-end',
    '--local-dir', './logs'
]

ray_environment = Environment.get(ws, name=ray_environment_name)
run_config = RunConfiguration(communicator='OpenMpi')
run_config.target = compute_target
run_config.node_count = 1
run_config.environment = ray_environment
command=["python", script_name, *script_arguments]

if video_capture:
    command = ["xvfb-run -s '-screen 0 640x480x16 -ac +extension GLX +render' "] + command
    run_config.environment_variables["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"

training_config = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='./files',
            command=command,
            run_config = run_config
            )

training_run = experiment.submit(training_config)
```

I get the following error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/xxx/code/Users/yyy/files'
```

Do you get what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

When the build fails of the environment variables creation, this error will occur. Instead of connecting the environment from the existing environment, we need to create the docker file.

[image]

[image]

The below code will be generated.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-cuda10.2-cudnn8-ubuntu18.04
RUN pip install azureml-mlflow

ray_env_build_details.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

After building the docker file if the case is successful go with the file location of the data and file and replace with the existing path.

[image]

If the screen is getting like above screen of the error, then the specific file path and directory error will be notified.

[image]

If the succeeded information is achieved, then we can access the data from the specific cluster. It will solve the error.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, I have some difficulties following the answer, e.g. I see the code `FROM ... RUN ...` generated, but not the `ray_env_build ...`. Should I replace `'cartpole-ray-sc'` with `nov999`  in the cell containing `ray_environment_name = 'cartpole-ray-sc'`? It would be great the entire solution could be captured in a notebook. Shouldn't the notebook be reproducible exactly like it is?

Comment: yes, replace with your own name. I kept as nov999 as trying to solve this post on nov9th. Replace the name with your own requirements.

Comment: Ok, I did like that, but I got the same error anyway. Probably I don't understand the resolution fully.

Comment: Once, try to execute the complete procedure again.